How do I draw on a GLArea with Cairo with gi-gtk (GTK3)?
I'am migrating a program from Gtk2Hs (GTK2) to gi-gtk (GTK3) and can't find how to draw on a GLArea (rendering OpenGL content) with cairo (additional informations).
In Gtk2Hs (GTK2) I used the function widgetGetDrawWindow on a GLDrawingArea. It gave me a DrawWindow on which I used renderWithDrawable.
Now, these functions seems to have disappeared and I'm a bit lost.
How do I draw with cairo on a gLArea using the gi-gtk API ?
Do you have an example even if it's in another language than Haskell ?

There is a dedicated section for cairo in the gtk2 to gtk3 migration guide. That being said it seems a questionable choice to migrate to an already obsolete toolkit when gtk4 has been released for 4 years already.
